# Naming big number of tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming-conventions

I need to create a database with a lot of similar tables (for example resistors). There are hundreds of tables with resistors of different types and parameters and I need to give names to all of them. Is there some rules of naming big number of tables that can help me?

Comment: Create a temporary table with names and write a cursor with dynamic sql to build tables.

Comment: Can't you put all resistors into a **single** table and have one (or a few) columns to distinguish their *different types* ?

Comment: No, it's not my design and they thought that it will be easier to create many tables.